# How to input the data from a txt file into a arraylist. Involving multiple data types and class objects that are variables for other classes

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I'm reading in data from different txt files to make objects and then into arraylists of the objects.

just as an example I have a teacher class with 3 or 4 varibles

```
public class Teacher {



        public static String teacherNo;
        public static String firstName;
        public static String lastName;
        public static Courses coursestought;
```

and a class Courses

```
public class Course {



        public static String cCode;
        public static String cName;
```

the constructor for the teacher class is like this

```
// constructor 
        public Teacher(String teacher_No,String first_Name,String last_Name, 
                Course coursesTought,)
```

I have all the right getters and setters(I think)

I read from the text file like this.

```
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader 
           ("pathtofile/teachers.txt"));
```

And I create the Teacher objects like this

```
String inputLine;
        inputLine = inFile.readLine();
        while (inputLine != null)
        {

            teacherlist.add(new Teacher
                    (inputLine, inputLine, inputLine, inputLine,));
            inputLine = inFile.readLine();
        }
```

But this only works if all the fields are strings not a mix of strings and variables and objects.  The fields in the text file are 1 line to a teacher and separated by :

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Do I need to cut up the strings as I read them in ?

Comment: You don't want the fields on `Teacher` or `Course` to be static - this means they exist only once for the class. Making them non-static will give each `Teacher` its own `firstname`, etc.

Comment: Also, you will want to use `Course[]` or `List<Course>` to hold multiple `Course` objects. Simply making a type plural doesn't do it for you!

Comment: @kublai khan  Its not shown but I do have an arraylist for the course objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use [String#split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the strings once you read them, create your objects and then add them to your arraylist

```
List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader 
           ("pathtofile/teachers.txt"));

String inputLine;
while ( (inputLine = inFile.readLine() ) != null) { // read one line at a time

    String[] teacherVars = inputLine.split(":"); // split into a string array.
    teachers.add(new Teacher(teacherVars[0], teacherVars[1], teacherVars[2], teacherVars[3]);
}
```

Not very clear from your question how the `Courses` object is represented in your text file. If thats variable length on the same line, you might have to do some additional magic to dynamically create the `Courses` object and then create the `Teacher` object.

Your instance variables inside class `Teacher` and `Courses` should not be static either. Static means class level and not object level.

If you have a Teacher class that looks like this ,

```
public class Teacher {

    private String teacherNo;
    ...
    private List<Course> courses;

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
       if ( courses == null)
          courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
       return courses;
    }
}
```

then, you could call it like this within your while loop --

```
while ( (inputLine = input.readLine() ) != null ) {
      Teacher teacher = new Teacher(teacherVar[0], teacherVar[1], teacherVar[2]);
      Course aCourse = new Course(teacherVar[3], teacherVar[4]);

      teacher.getCourses().add(aCourse);
}
```

This is assuming your teacher line in text has a course code and course name as part of it.

Comment: the course data comes in in their own separate txt file.  Thanks for the tip about Static. Since all the variables have a getter and setter they should be private right?

Comment: Correct. They should be private. You would still need a way to relate the Teacher with the Course. Hopefully the course data contains teacherNo. Also, if you want to populate course data separately, you should get rid of Course from the constructor of teacher.

Comment: actually I've made a bit of a mistake here the teacher data is like this 845698:billy:bob:ccode1:ccode2:ccode3:ccode4:
So I guess that means i'll put the first 3 into a teacher object,Then make a list of the 4 fields for the course variable.

Comment: Yes. You could do that or you could pass the entire array into your Teacher constructor and let him make the Course objects for you.

Comment: something like this?
teachers.add(new Teacher(teacherVars[0], teacherVars[1], teacherVars[2], course.add(new Course (teacherVars[3], teachervars[4],teacherVars[5] );

Comment: Thanks for all the work you've put in. I have a much clearer idea now.
thanks again.

Comment: You may want to read the "course" text file before the "teacher" text file.  And I would probably use some kind of Map.  I don't think that Kal's answer is correct.  I think that looping from teacherVar[3] to teacherVar[teacherVar.length - 1] would be the right thing to do.